# Bounds on the sum of $f(x)/x$ given bounds on $f(x)$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

In particular, I am interested in bounding
$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\phi(k)}{k}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\theta(k)}{k}$ where $\phi(k)$ is Euler's totient function and $\theta(k)$ is the number of square-free divisor of $k$.

The wiki-page for Euler's totient has the formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\phi(k)}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\mu(k)}{k}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor = \frac{6}{\pi^2}n + O\left( (\log n)^{2/3}(\log \log n)^{4/3} \right)$$

however, looking at the source cited:
*Walfisz, Arnold (1963). Weylsche Exponentialsummen in der neueren Zahlentheorie. Mathematische Forschungsberichte (in German). Vol. 16. Berlin: VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften. Zbl 0146.06003*,

The digitized text states:

$$\sum_{n<x}\phi(n) = \frac{3}{\pi^2}x^2 + O\left( x(\log x)^{2/3}(\log \log x)^{4/3} \right)$$

For one, to the best of my knowledge, the error bound has on the summatory totient is $O(x \log(x))$, this is worse than $O\left( x(\log x)^{2/3}(\log \log x)^{4/3} \right)$, correct? And second, the scanned text does not seem to have this formula (to the best of my understanding, I cannot read German)
Finally, neither the digitized text nor the scanned text have the formula mentioned on the wiki page.

Finally, this brings me to a broader question: **if we know the asymptotic behavior of $f(x)$, what can we conclude about the asymptotic behavior of $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{f(n)}{n}$?**

Intuitively, I would guess if $f(x)$ is bounded by some polynomial $p(n)$, then $F(x)$ would be bounded by $\frac{p(n)}{n}$. Is this the case? This guess *mostly* aligns with the formula for $\phi(n)$ and $\sum_{k<n} \frac{\phi(k)}{k}$, both in the primary term and the error term given by the sources above.

Comment: If you feel that your question has been adequately answered, the customary thing to do is to accept the answer by hitting the check mark next to it. If flags the question as being resolved so no one else will try to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given asymptotic knowledge about $\sum_{n=1}^{x}f(n)$, one can learn about $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{f(n)}{n}$ using [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) by writting

$$\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{f(n)}{n}=\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{x}f(n)\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}f(n)\right)\cdot\frac{1}{k(k-1)}.$$

Plugging in whatever assympotic formula one has for $\sum_{n=1}^{x}f(n)$, an immediate formula is then returned for $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{f(n)}{n}$.